# How can I find the number of pairs a,b<N such that GCD(a,b) = x?

Tags: c++, math, primes, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to solve [the SPOJ problem PGCD](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PGCD/), which asks how many primes appear in a table of greatest common divisors.

The first idea that came to my mind is to generate the primes first by sieving.

Then, for each prime *p*, see how many pairs (*a*, *b*), where *a* and *b* are less than the given bounds, satisfy `GCD(a,b)=p`.

For example, how many pairs less than (20, 20) satisfy GCD(a,b)=7?

Of course, as mentioned, *a* and *b* are bounded.

So is it possible to reverse GCD? Or is this solution completely invalid?

Comment: Of course not. You talk about primes. Any 2 primes have the GCD 1. What results do you expect from `rev_GCD(1)`? There are infinitely many pairs that would be valid results.

Comment: am expecting the count of that.. as if how many pairs (a,b) satisfy that

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the GCD function is not reversible/invertible because, for example,

- GCD(10,15) == 5
- GCD(5, 15) == 5

So if you are given 5 and try to guess the inputs, it is impossible.

I might be missing something here because I don't understand what you're saying about the bounding, but I think that's your responsibility to explain the problem better.  Exactly what information do you have and what information are you trying to calculate?  Example inputs and ouputs would be really useful.  Also, proofreading and spell-checking.

Comment: let the bound be 5 for both a,b
then how many pairs (a,b) satisfy GCD(a,b)=2
the answer is 3
the pairs are (2,2) (2,4) and (4,2)